# Access to the replication's properties, MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have ms sql server 2005.
What should I do for user who are not sa or db_owner to view replication's properties?
I've read BOL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151221(v=sql.90).aspx, but it didn't help. User with replmonitor role can only see all pubcations, but can't view their properties!

Answer (score 0):

According to [Security Role Requirements for Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152528%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), to view publication properties a user must be a member of the PAL, db_owner database role on the publication database at the Publisher, or sysadmin server role on the Publisher.

Comment: Add them to the PAL (Publication Access List)

Comment: Of course I did, but it didn't help. Only users with sa or db_owner rights can see this properties :( I have transactional replication and there is an interesting article about PAL in such transactions: [link](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/joe/when-is-the-publication-access-list-required/)

Comment: Yes, I did some testing for Joe on that one and it seems as if Transactional Replication does not respect the PAL in some cases :(

Comment: So we have given this users access to some replication Views.